# Laravel store data with data array

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to store data into database, this is the input view :
[image: input-view]

I just want to store the data with this code :

```
$data = $request->date;
$sub_kriteria_id = $request->sub_kriteria_id;
$karyawan_id = $request->karyawan_id;
$nilai = $request->nilai;
$kriteria = $request->kriteria;

// $d = count($karyawan_id);

foreach ($nilai as $key => $i) {
    foreach ($karyawan_id as $key2 => $val) {
        $data = Penilaian::create([
            'date' => $date,
            'karyawan_id' => $karyawan_id[$key2],
            'sub_kriteria_id' => $sub_kriteria_id[$key2],
            'nilai' => $nilai[$key],
        ]);
    }
}
```

but the result is not expected, like this:
[image: actual-results-in-database]

How to make this data can stored into database like this :
[image: expected-results-in-database]

Please advice if you have the solution, thank you master.

Comment: like what ? what is your desire output ?

Comment: duplicated input happen in my code, in the last picture is my desire output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I get this correctly, there are many ways to prevent double submissions:

- one way is to disable the button on the front end and then once the form is submitted you could show a success message and then you could redirect the user to another page.
- You can also combine this with server side validations to prevent this as well
- As well as the above, you can also make some validation on the database itself.

Comment: this issue already done, so I put the 2 steps for store that data, but I think isn't good practice but it's work.